# Adding a condition to every query in a model

Tags: yii

I have a system where all tables in the MySQL database are populated with external data (synchronized with another system every 5 minutes). All tables have a column `DELFLAG` which is used to mark disabled entries.

So I have about 15 AR models in Yii that are linked to those tables. Whenever I make a query, I need to add something like `$criteria->addCondition('DELFLAG=0')`. This gets ugly if there are multiple tables present in the query, as every one of them has the flag. Also, there's a potential for error if I forget one of those conditions.

Here's how I do it now:

```
public function search($showtype = NULL) {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    if (isset($showtype)) {
        $criteria->with = array(
            'TSSSHOW',
            'TSSSHOW.TSSSHOWTYPEITEM',
            'TSSSHOW.TSSSHOWTYPEITEM.TSSSHOWTYPE'
        );
        $criteria->compare('TSSSHOWTYPEITEM.TSSSHOWTYPEID', $showtype);
        $criteria->addCondition('TSSSHOW.DELFLAG=0');
        $criteria->addCondition('TSSSHOWTYPEITEM.DELFLAG=0');
    }

    $exp = new CDbExpression("`TSSEVENT_START_DATETIME` > NOW()");
    $criteria->addCondition($exp);
    $criteria->addCondition('t.DELFLAG=0');
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->order = 't.TSSEVENT_START_DATETIME ASC';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pageSize' => 15,
        ),
    ));
}
```

Is there a convenient way to include this condition into every query that includes these tables? Perhaps a special class which my models shall descend from (as opposed to the default `CActiveRecord`)?

Comment: All your table have such condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest declaring named scope for these models:

```
public function scopes()
{
    return array(
        'disabledEntry'=>array(
            'condition'=>'DELFLAG=1',
        ),
    );
}
```

Using the named scope: `Model::model()->disabledEntry()->findAll();`
You can provide scope when relaring to model in the with() statement as well: `ModelA::model()->with('model:disabledEntry')->findAll();`

But if you have to set this condition each time, you may set defaultScope:

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array(    
        'condition' => 'DELFLAG=0',
    );      
}
```

Thus, this model by default would have this condition.

**Update:** Since you have the identically named columns in several models, YII can have some column name ambiguity troubles while building sql-query. If it is the case, use `alias` in scope declaration or use the following statement to set current table alias explicitly while declaring scope `'condition' => $this->getTableAlias(false, false) . '.DELFLAG=0',`

Comment: Thank you, `defaultScope` exactly what I need (with `getTableAlias`).

Answer (score 0):

You can create Your own class e.g. CustomActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord
then You should override findAll, findByPk methods with your criteria..

Other solution is to run this query 'DELETE FROM table_name WHERE DELFLAG=1' after every import..

Comment: I can't actually delete these entries from the DB as it will break the sync system. As for the methods you mention, I don't think they are called at all. At least the way I'm using the `CActiveDataProvider`.

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to do. I guess I'll have to also extend the models, so that the new data provider class will tell my special models from ordinary ones.

Comment: In models generated by gii, I change search method to look like this: $criteria->compare('deleted',0);

Comment: Or you can try to override beforeFindInternal() method in CActiveRecord